# How to animate a SVG with CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I try to animate a SVG with CSS, but it wouldn't work as I thought.
First I create an animation for text DIV's-> that works fine. Then I use the same animation for the SVG path and here the automation runs complete different as for the text. Is it a bug? Or is it the wrong way to animate SVG?

```css
 svg {
      border: solid 1px;
    }

    .deckel {
      animation: ani1 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    .tank {
      animation: ani2 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .wo {
      animation: ani3 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .wm {
      animation: ani4 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .wu {
      animation: ani5 5s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    @keyframes ani1 {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      16% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    @keyframes ani2 {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      33% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    @keyframes ani3 {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    @keyframes ani4 {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      67% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    @keyframes ani5 {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      83% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
```

```html
  <div class="deckel">
    Text1
  </div>
  <div class="tank">
    Text2
  </div>
  <div class="wo">
    Text3
  </div>
  <div class="wm">
    Text4
  </div>
  <div class="wu">
    Text5
  </div>

  <svg width="300" height="300">
    <rect class="deckel" x="50" y="0" width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" />
    <rect class="tank" x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" />
    <rect class="wo" x="50" y="100" width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" />
    <rect class="wm" x="50" y="150" width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" />
    <rect class="wu" x="50" y="200" width="50" height="50" style="fill:blue;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;" />
  </svg>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean "runs completely differently"?. Both text and SVG animation seem to work as far as I can see.

Comment: The SVG Path's do not appear at the same time as the texts? I'm using Firefox 68.2.0esr.

Comment: Seems like a Firefox bug. Feel free to [report it](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=SVG)